# C# Change Excel Chart Axis Format using EPPLUS

Tags: c#, .net, epplus

Is there anyway to change the chart X or Y axis to set a custom label formatting?

For example, in the XAxis my labels are datetime but the formatting is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss. I would like to change it to just yyyy-mm-dd.

Was wondering if it is possible in EPPLUS without using interop

Comment: You can do this now - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39103496/c-sharp-change-excel-chart-label-orientation-using-epplus/74570591#74570591

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bit of a pain with charts and EPPlus.  They have exposed the `chart.XAxis.Format` property to set the format but does not account for the attribute `souceLinked` which, when not set to 0 (default) tells excel to just go with the source data format.  So you have to set it manually with xml:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Chart_Row_Offset_Test()
{
    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[]
    {
        new DataColumn("Col1", typeof (DateTime)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col3", typeof (object))
    });

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow();
        row[0] =  DateTime.Now.AddDays(i) ;row[1] = i*10;row[2] = Path.GetRandomFileName();
        datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Create a test file
    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Chart_Row_Offset.xlsx");
    if (fi.Exists)
        fi.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var workbook = pck.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);

        //This would be the axis label format if the XML Attribute is not set below
        worksheet.Cells["A2:A11"].Style.Numberformat.Format = "m/d/yyyy";

        const int EXCELCHARTWIDTH = 375;
        const int EXCELCHARTHEIGHT = 350;
        const double EXCELDEFAULTROWHEIGHT = 20.0; //Assuming standard screen dpi

        var startCell = (ExcelRangeBase)worksheet.Cells["A1"];
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            var chart = worksheet.Drawings.AddChart("chart " + i, eChartType.XYScatterLines);
            chart.SetSize(EXCELCHARTWIDTH, EXCELCHARTHEIGHT);
            chart.SetPosition(startCell.Start.Row, 0, startCell.Start.Column, 0);
            chart.XAxis.Format = "yyyy-mm-dd";

            var series = chart.Series.Add(worksheet.Cells["B2:B11"], worksheet.Cells["A2:A11"]);

            var chartcellheight = (int)Math.Ceiling(EXCELCHARTHEIGHT / EXCELDEFAULTROWHEIGHT);
            startCell = startCell.Offset(chartcellheight, 0);

            //Get reference to the chart xml for proper namespace
            var xdoc = chart.ChartXml;
            var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xdoc.NameTable);
            nsm.AddNamespace("default", xdoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);

            //Add the attribute to not link to the source data format
            var att = xdoc.CreateAttribute("sourceLinked");
            att.Value = "0";
            var numFmtNode = xdoc.SelectSingleNode("/default:chartSpace/default:chart/default:plotArea/default:valAx/default:numFmt", nsm);
            numFmtNode.Attributes.Append(att);
        }

        pck.Save();
    }


}
```

Comment: Will this work on an existing file and worksheet? The method works but when I adapt it to my code (which is roughly the same with the exception of opening an existing sheet)

I used the xml related code and I got this error message under try-catch:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Nvm I got it. Mine was catAx instead of ValAx