# C# Change Excel chart label orientation using EPPlus

Tags: c#, xml, epplus-4

There doesn't seem to be any method in EPPlus for changing the orientation of tick labels on a chart.

I can see it's possible to make changes by using the XML properties exposed by ChartXML but documentation for this seems to be thin on the ground. Can anybody help me out here, please?

Thanks

John

Answer (score 0):

Newer version of Epplus (from 5 onwards I think) support this - you can use Axis.TextBody.Rotation and set it between -90 and 90.

```
chart.XAxis.TextBody.Rotation = -90;
```